# Ошибка "unable to open database file" SQLite3 Python

Tags: python, sqlite3

Пишу телеграмм бота, используя в проекте библиотеку `sqlite3`. Все работало отлично, до момента, как я почистил свой компьютер при помощи CCleaner.

Код начал выдавать ошибку "unable to open database file". Проблема возникает, когда код пытается изменить таблицу (при помощи `UPDATE`). Потому что когда код берет значение из таблицы (при помощи `SELECT`), все работает (команда `sqlite3.connect()` выполняется верно). Кроме того, сама таблица тоже отлично открывается прям из папки проекта.

Часть кода:

```
def add_city(id_user, city_from_user):
    try:
        db = sqlite3.connect('C:\\Users\\user1\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Pythonproject\\telegram_bot\\telebot_database.db')
        c = db.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT city_01,city_02 FROM telebot WHERE rowid = ?",[id_user])
        result_select = c.fetchone()
        if result_select[0] is None:
            c.execute("UPDATE telebot SET city_01 = ? WHERE rowid = ?",[city_from_user,id_user])
        else:
            c.execute("UPDATE telebot SET city_02 = ? WHERE rowid = ?",[city_from_user,id_user])
        db.commit()
        return "ready"
    except sqlite3.Error as e:
        print("Error:", e)
    finally:
        c.close()
        db.close()
```

Как я понял, проблема заключается в том, что у моего кода нет просто доступа к изменению файла.

Comment: Что вам мешает проверить вашу теорию с отсутствием прав?

Comment: Я просто не знаю как это сделать

Comment: Запускаете проект, смотрите в процессах, от чьего имени он работает, далее смотрите разрешения на ваши файлы и если для пользователя нет прав на изменение, то добавляете. Детали зависят от вашей ОС, в которой вы работаете.

Comment: Проверил, разрешения везде есть, попробовал ещё переустановить VSCode, не помогло. Я не понимаю в чем проблема, пробывал запускать тот же самый код в простой IDLE python, все работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Случайным образом, я выявил, что данная проблема возникает из-за антивируса Windows 10, а именно из-за функции "Защита от программ-шантажистов". Надо **выключить "Контролируемый доступ к папкам"** и проблема исчезает.

[image: функция windows 10]

Примечание: добавить процесс в исключения, мне не помогло.